# magento 2.2.3 how to add a new cms block or new phtml to product page

Tags: product, catalog, phtml, cms-block

I want to add a new cms block or PHTML to the product page. 
I have the following files `composer.json`, `etc/module.xml`, and `registration.php`
I have `view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.main">
           <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="staticblock" template="module_name::staticblock.phtml">
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

I have the `.phtml` template file ->

```
<h1>TEST BLOCK DID IT WORK</h1>
```

I want this to be appearing after the product info detailed (tabs) like at the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created module, Check the below files

> app/code/Vendor/Module/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Module.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

class Module extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context  $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getText()
    {
        //Your block code
        return __('Hello Developer! This how to get the storename: %1 and this is the way to build a url: %2', $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getName(), $this->getUrl('contacts'));
    }
}
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/module.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * @var $block \Vendor\Module\Block\Module
 */
?>
<div>
    <?= $block->getText(); ?>
    <h1>TEST BLOCK DID IT WORK</h1>
</div>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block as="module" class="Vendor\Module\Block\Module" name="module" template="Vendor_Module::module.phtml" after="product.info.details"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

This module is working for me, Please check below screenshot

[image]

Comment: Hello @Kishor I am looking at this now

Comment: Nothing appears the phtml doesn't load up unfortunately

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: No erros nothing in my debug.log or even system.logs so i am stuck

Comment: Have you changed "module_name::staticblock.phtml" with your module name?

Comment: Yes, I did that as well

Comment: Do i need to do set:di:compile? or anything

Comment: Not needed, Just flush the cache.

Comment: I have done that c:f but no result :(, I am not sure if i am missing anything or if something is blocking

Comment: I have updated my answer, Please check, Hope this will help you

Comment: I am looking at it now thank you i will let you know soon as possible

Comment: It still not working for me, Is there anything could be blocking in core xml file? like just for me

Comment: hi @Kishor i accepted your answer thank you so much